# Return types for utility functions of React Testing Library

Tags: typescript, react-testing-library

I'm trying to figure out what should the return type be (instead of generic : any) for the utilities returned by Testing Library React.

For example, with the following, I get TS error (Unexpected any. Specify a different type.)

```
const setup = (): any => {
              //~~~~~ Unexpected any. Specify a different type.
  const utils = render(
...
  );
  const button = utils.getByText(/some text/i);
  return { button, ...utils };
};
test('it renders', () => {
  const { button } = setup();
  expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`setup` returns an object of the type T which you need to find out. It has:

- `key: value` where the name of the `key` is the string 'button' and `value` is `typeof button` which is `JSX.Element`.
- All the keys and the values that are inside the type returned by `render()`. Which the  spread operator injects directly into the type T. You didn't show the body of `render()`. I guess it returns also `JSX.Element`.

So we have

```js
type T = {
  button: JSX.Element
  ...
  // the internals of JSX.Element that spread operator directly injects here
  ...
}
```

I had to give `render()` a body with sample code. And we have:

```js
const render = (): JSX.Element => {
  const MyButton = () => ( <div>Hello </div> )
  return (
    <>
    <MyButton />
    </>
  )
};

type T = {
  type: any;
  props: any;
  key: string | number | null;
  button: JSX.Element;
};

const setup = (): T => {
  const utils = render();
  const button =  <div>Hello </div>;
  return { button, ...utils };
};
```